# Why is `i` commonly used for indices and other variable name choices?

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, semantics

I always use `i` in loops as an iterating variable, and `j` for nested loops. `m` is always a matrix, `p` and `q` for nodes, etc. I learned it this way, and it seems to be fairly universal, but why?

Is it a case where I learned it from my professor, he from his, he from his, etc until you reach the very first programmers, or is there intrinsic meaning to why `i` is used for iteration? I know `i` fits because it's the first letter in `iterator`, but what of `j`, `m`, `p`, `q`, etc?

I did a little digging and it seems `i` comes from mathematics, where it is commonly used for summations. This doesn't explain other variables, however.

Comment: Duplicate of this programmers.se question: [Why do most of us use 'i' as a loop counter variable?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general programming conventions and history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to resources that have turned into dust -- this tradition goes back to the early version of `FORTRAN` where certain variables were either `integer` or `real`, depending on their starting letter.

`i` was the first integer, and so it made sense for loops.

This is also explains the old joke of:

God is real
-- Unless declared as an Integer

Comment: I'd actually never heard that joke before!

Comment: That's actually quite clever.

Answer (score 2):

Back in days of FORTRAN (and I'm talking FORTRAN IV, not this new-fangled Fortran 77 or other malarkey), variables whose names began with letters in the range I to N were implicitly of INTEGER type, unless you declared them explicitly as anything else. Anything outside that range were implicitly REAL unless you said otherwise. So looping on I and J were "free" and became commonplace.